# excel vba - code doesn't run on old sheet but does on new one

Tags: excel, vba

I have some excel sheets obtained from an online program that converts from PDF to excel and am trying to process the data these have. However, when I try to run this code:

```
Sheets(1).Range("A1").Select
    For j = 1 To 16
        If Selection.Offset(j, 0) = 1 Then
           Selection.Offset(j, 0).Select
        End If
    Next j
```

Excel shows the `runtime-error '1004': application-defined or object-defined error`.

However, if I create a new worksheet, the code runs with no problem. Why can't I run my code on the other worksheets?

Other instructions like `Selection.Offset(2, 0) = Sheet(1).Range("A1")` work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid using the Select, when possible.

```
With Sheets(1)
    For j = 2 To 17
        If .Cells(j, 1) = 1 Then
           .Cells(j, 1).Select
        End If
    Next j
End With
```